# Немогу понять почему возвращаются не перемешанные списки, а три None

Tags: python

Вот код

```
from random import shuffle

lst_in = ['1 2 3 4', '5 6 7 8', '9 8 6 7']
lst_in = [shuffle(i.split()) for i in lst_in]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что функция `shuffle` ничего не возвращает. Она только изменяет переданный ей список, т.к. список — ссылочный тип данных

Так что для получения ожидаемого результата, вам просто не нужно перезаписывать список в переменную `lst_in`.

Вот так:

```py
from random import shuffle

lst_in = [i.split() for i in ['1 2 3 4', '5 6 7 8', '9 8 6 7']]

for i in lst_in:
    shuffle(i)
```

Или также, через генератор, но без записи в переменную

```py
[shuffle(i) for i in lst_in]
```